# I need a shorter access to my jQuery Plugin methods

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

Probably a question answered like this already, but after searching a while I cannot find a definitive answer that matches this pattern.

So at its most basic level my plugin looks like the below, all I want to be able to do once an element has passed through this is be able to have a short reference to the plugin's methods, something like:

Init plugin on element:

```
$('#myElement').myPlugin({ options });
```

Then to access a method:

```
$('#myElement').myPlugin('myFirstMethod', { params });
```

Here's the plugin shell:

```
;(function($) {
    "use strict";
    var plugin = {};
    var defaults = {
        myDefault:        'some_value'
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options){        

        if(this.length > 1){
            this.each(function(){$(this).myPlugin(options);});
            return this;
        }

        var myplugin = {};
        var element = this;
        plugin.element = this;

        var init = function() {
            myplugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            // Other init stuff here
        };

        form.myFirstMethod = function(){
            // Do something
        };

        form.mySecondMethod = function(){
            // Do something else
        };

        init();
        return this; // returns the current jQuery object

    }

})(jQuery);
```

Again, I'm sure this must be answered somewhere. I just need the 'shortest' access to the methods.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I hate calling methods by `pluginName('method', 'params')` because it doesn't give you the full toolkit that javascript provides. Also, I do not like calling the same method for two different purposes. In your case you want `$().myPlugin()` to init and `$().myPlugin("methodName")` to execute a method. That's one method `myPlugin()` for two entirely different purposes. But if that's the way you wanna roll, the following snippet should suffice I believe.

```
// plugin
(function($) {
    var myplugin = function(elm) {
        this.elm = $(elm);
    };

    myplugin.prototype.myFirstMethod = function() { console.log("firstmethod"); }
    myplugin.prototype.mySecondMethod = function() { console.log("secondmethod"); }

    $.fn.myplugin = function() {
        var myArgs = arguments;
        return this.each(function() {
            if (!$(this).data("myplugin")) {
                $(this).data("myplugin", new myplugin(this));
            }

            var api = $(this).data("myplugin");

            if (myArgs.length > 0) {
                api[myArgs[0]](myArgs[1]);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

// init plugin
$(".foo").myplugin();

$(".foo").myplugin("myFirstMethod");
```

Keep in mind if you want to execute this method on every element of a jquery collection you'll want to do an `each` and execute.

Does that work?

Comment: I definitely do not want to have to have a defined variable for every instance of my plugin like api above. If it can be made to be usable like: `$('#foo').myFirstMethod(params);` then that would be even better.

Comment: And before it is said, what I am trying to get away from is: `$('#foo').data('myPlugin').myFirstMethod(params);` unless this is my only resort here.

Comment: Is this plugin going to apply to many nodes, each with their own instance, or will there largely only be one per page?

Comment: One to many. This plugin is for forms and will basically be called like: `$('form').myPlugin({options});`

Comment: To be usable like that : `$('#foo').myFirstMethod(params);` you need to create a prototype of jquery : `$.fn.method`

Comment: Tomas I have amended my answer to provide `$("#foo").myPlugin("methodName", { params })` like you specified in your original question. It's not a syntax I like, but if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Although your answer does work, it suggests that I need to completely restructure my plugin pattern which I'm not willing to accept. I'll need to find a specific way with my plugin pattern. Which I don't imagine that will be difficult at this point.